# defaultdict of list

Tags: python, html, css, django

```
>>> example = defaultdict(list)
>>> example['key'].append(1)
>>> example
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'key': [1]})
```

I am using defaultdict for a list in my django app
but a want to obtan an output witout <{}[]
is it possible?

Comment: Neither your input nor your output is syntactically correct Python.

Comment: i did modification , can you check please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must create your data.
Second, you get the keys of your data.
At, last, you must loop each key.

You can use the following code which is self-explainable:

```
import collections
info=collections.defaultdict(list,{'List of tubes': ['2324', '98', '7654'], 'List of auto:': [147, 10048, 1009, 10050, 10, 1647, 10648, 649, 1005]})
#print(info)
keys=info.keys()
for key in keys: # loop for each key
  print(f'\'{key}\': ',end='')
  tmp=info[key]
  for i,data in enumerate(tmp):
    if isinstance(data, str): # for the string type
      if i!=len(tmp)-1:
        print('\'%s\', '%(data),end='')
      else:
        print('\'%s\''%(data),end='')
    else:  # for the int type
      if i!=len(tmp)-1:
        print('%d, '%(data),end='')
      else:
        print('%d'%(data),end='')
  print()
```